# Update array based on current time

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have an array of times that I got from my database.

```
let list = ["15:15", "15:30", "15:45", "16:00", "16:15", "16:30", "16:45", "17:00", "17:15", "17:30", "17:45", "18:00"];
```

I want to update and remove the element when the time has expired.

Is there a way to do this without the use of setInterval method?

thanks.

Comment: Are the expired times updated periodically on your array or it's done once?

Comment: it needs to be periodically so that I can show the times available left in the array

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample to remove expired time intervals from the array:

```js
let list = ["13:01", "15:30", "15:45", "16:00", "16:15", "16:30", "16:45", "17:00", "17:15", "17:30", "17:45", "18:00"];
let currentTime = moment().format("HH:mm");
let result = list.filter(x => x > currentTime);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample is using **Moment** to find the current timezone.

Answer (score 0):

There is, two ways one is setInterval, and setTimeout. You can use anyone of this. If you don't want to use these two inbuilt functions. Then, you need to do some manual calculations using some manual methods.

You can do, cookie concept, also...

Comment: Hey welcome to SO. Maybe you can explain to @we22gz what the difference between setTimeout ans setInterval is and when to use which.